# Remove HTML tag with PHP, when user is in mainpage.com

Tags: php, html

I have this tag in PHP file, and I need to remove it when user is in Main Page (mainpage.com example).

I don't need to hide it with CSS or JS, just remove from DOM.

I have searched the web, but can't find nothing (maybe it's my mistake) (also I'm a frontend Angularjs developer)

So how can I do it with PHP?

```
<td class="category" width="20">
     <a>
          ...
     </a>
</td>
```

Comment: You mean that this code is in a file that is include in multiple pages, and you want to exclude some code from that file for a single page? `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/') { ... }` should do?

Comment: @jcaron Yes , this code is include in every pages of website , i need to remove it only from main page

Comment: The answer is in my comment then. Add the appropriate `<?php` and `?>` in the right places, of course.

Comment: @halfer , will done :)

Comment: @jcaron Can you write a right answer below please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally will control by PHP 'IF' condition, but need depend how your website detect current page is main page.

If you home page URL look like:

- mainpage.com
- mainpage.com/index.php

I then the example below should help you up :)

```
<?php if(!(strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') == '/' || strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') == '/index.php')):?>
<td class="category" width="20">
     <a>
          ...
     </a>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks sir :) very simple

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make an if else conditional for current url. To get current url in PHP you can read this question 
[Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

```
if ($url === 'http://mainpage.com/') {
//function here 
enter code here
} else {
// do nothing 
}
```

To remove the content of certain element you can use **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** function. I tested this code bellow and it's worked.

```
$html = '<div id="somediv">Some div</div>
    <td class="category" width="20">
    <a> ...  </a> </td>

    <td class="anothercategory" width="20">
    <a>
    Not removed
    </a>
    </td><
    <div class="someclas"> Another Part</div>';

echo  preg_replace('/<td class="category"[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/td[^>]*>/', ' Removed ', $html);
```

Please combine that two code based on your case. Hope it's help